# IIS WWWROOT deleted recovered from temp but is encrepted

Tags: iis, encryption

I have by mistakenly deleted Permanently the IIS 7 WWWROOT folder is there a way to recover 
i  found a solution was that it has a temp folder where all the data was stored but when am trying to open the html file is encrypted is there a way to decrypt the data
the root directory is as below

`C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\DefaultAppPool\$^_gzip_C^\INETPUB\WWWROOT`

and the file encrypted data is

```
‹      ¬ûoÛ6úgØÿÀi;H¾rÜÝ‡Xv&Ê-¸4    u[QäYbl5²äRt“`Ëÿ~Ÿ¢^†º´h$‘üÞòãgï‡³ëÓàÃÖt“Î¿ÿÎ“ïWD$ÙRThf­)ÝÇá§ðÉ]åù*Åá6)Ü(ßð¹qš,‹ñ§Ï;LžÇ÷?îÏràn’ÌýTXso,ÈµR.ú’~ãNÜIÒìsÀþîwYD“<CiÆaš:Cô'›´=¾„\ìRZ úÉ±”#{øñðnªa’X.'qmå>!½
7Xèq
.
+`jXƒÚ®óLðoc]E‡ßRxlpFÜ:]ø'‚“·—>º8GW×òÿ¸¸
nÑižÑ0ýœ$¾Ï X]\þýºY\¼;Y|@ÿó? “÷ÁõÅÐyç_#C­ÀÿÆZ|1r²ï¡UJ_àGô$M+²Ýú—þi€þ‰Î×ï´8Z’˜Ð
ÎÅÕ­¿˜ ×†Z¨R)ÊývrùÞ¿EÎñ±ÿ¦X»m\·×û›3f/MúÖ*ž<64æ#å˜côû¯þÂql0‰I¾­°8[\ßH‡´èƒ©j2@¦Š•4·™âURXR¾ÅÙYHÃeX`Ç:‰cßâmž?X#dMÜCö’³HN¿9dÿ††(€_`*&Dlá2ÅÎÐà¨³*Ï|BrâÐ§ÂìK¥× LÁ‹Ÿs7À0\aIá¥…N±Î8ÊI\èÈäs“,Ãä×àÝ%¨hÛ‚È ^º”„YrŽ¢’hü}rñŽv`ÚÏ©ÓŒÇúxÁ]¢Ždú—$ÒÀZ,¹$,¦jR9<jàp„ _Ù.M§0ç)sº)ÎVt
sñ„WPlè$CM~PÙƒÜpŽÛ£dîÑxŽ—dÛE„g1³¢5Ž–É“…¾„éÏ¬à7Ñç-VK9,eÅrüñŽmž@ˆóÒp‰Ó¹¸m½)ÝÁ”íÅz•#çSä÷ÅçTq¢ø‰Zøy·Y›çsmß5lëc¨%ìbÇãœæˆK8B­2–ûk›¦@m·9©JÙ³ÆÑR¼ZH ÖIãÌb‰kÁ™Ñ¢¼ÚŒëÊïŒÁß¶õ!ß/
øeOÎU’[Åä×§Uíü9eäóHm}d›¿À|PµC„Ò~¾-wt5æ{º€¬\8Éâ†´lh0¨*20žmJ1ZR¥DÌ7}Ù_à(!«šhÀ2¡$œ¡¡e…‚HâÚ28wÝÞGéë½U;’¿Ò[°ëÆýüÖy-Z±³ûÕYQ) úç;ó0=ÏÉÆÙ“%¦’•ã²Š:¨œªjÓ$£$ßGß ¤ˆ7£QŸÄðÓ+Õ€ÓÓF”•Dò(d¼]‚™vN%µá@t¹xp‚ì(M¢{TŠl–)Xì5hs›‘–9­©ƒÁ¤[{Äy´cnvW˜ú)÷øÛç‹Ø±¶LÍ²ÛºqR02¬P¤d‡»©u=^*×™Òê¦#ÕnGŽû˜dqþèflp¾£e+7óKÒ=ÅDáÐDU‡&{°äm+È5ÎA0)œ€º‚|¥¹ÆcÀÍÓ©@P1Ú¢kŒ–;JYc^'%Ù
ÒŒ/ðÃ´hI‰òö:ÌVñj )×7¬Ã÷lVM˜ËâÆÔu„X1tq­
ë]‚¡°+ T§±  È4¹GÿafÛC1§È|­
ïÃ´ÀŠxa˜yÑÒ1’æK-ùZ]³-r°¶.Ó÷'a—†$@C7)Ë4®5Dý…š0t
+åNL0Ý‘¬ªm©3|„ù×aqÊê6Ç·ú’Ðëí2PŒh¾Z¥¸Á«k"æ˜p¼ÂíxA
uÿDUmö½€<%®o_7`…X­`vKô5Ø^CôµhKàVCXûDçÑë”±«#…1cû‘ˆw»–ýÊÑ¥€Û0Ó2±Ž›cW”k®Wv×.áÏ’—ØXz¬•§(Äti`æŸÖË¸Û»ÚIdô¢<›u&_†Ò·üÐª2na8ÙÇ‘+Ýùò~Ž*+I_~›†’îëÈŽ\µ—ôµÚLÿ¶åÍg7Ä$‰›hß¶Õ£âîu‡  #°;Â]µ¦”£UQWqjVGÍX=½Úåˆ?DkÌì¹}«æk0L¬¿iÁý-Gš3û{dÿÛ¶†S„Ú·Nf‰jGž>§˜7äËm‹°£‡ÉwY|õ{<5°Š·Æa¬šùÞX¼e?CqÇ¼1³tkjqÐJ÷Çì½°ÖËx~Îâ‚·ÁŽ”Ó¼%Ï/ÃÖév‰9jÐ]%F•ßra">D1*ÛBü~bÍù•
±{Š7 `NN
W„¶5Ïß­ˆRÜk¬ùïƒd÷ÍÏà…øýF— yÆ< ®„òÔB­ˆœeSh   €˜@,nŸ@œ¦pœEP³èDIL×ðuxøá¯ëgŠˆôèZ~
Š0–sc=¹™÷É¸c.†þHJÕ_,îyØ‚•tlwþêv—>5T€uÙ£_3mèöâsqòEKYÚXóÉòXqRJÇ€ƒxÎ|òY?ý‘6‘Å!Ôù_¹?Æ/|+b;}ÿlKâÓÿ #ì±dK
```

Comment: Given the folder name, I would suggest it's GZip compressed, not encrypted.

Comment: @which folder thanks for the reply

Comment: Part of the path is the folder "IIS Temporary **Compressed** Files" and then there's also "$^_gzip_C^"

Comment: @Iridium exactly in the same place where i founded my backup data but when am trying to open the data inside a html page is as above